# Dynamically select matching subset of columns for each row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I dynamically obtain the subset of all columns in pandas where the category of each level is i.e. `a`?
It is fine to keep the original dimensions of `df` and fill the rest with null values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9},
 'level_1__category': {0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'a',
  3: 'a',
  4: 'a',
  5: 'c',
  6: 'a',
  7: 'b',
  8: 'a'},
 'level_1__value': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 10, 8: 34},
 'level_2__category': {0: 'c',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'd',
  3: 'a',
  4: 'a',
  5: 'b',
  6: 'b',
  7: np.nan,
  8: np.nan},
 'level_2__value': {0: 2.0,
  1: 3.0,
  2: 5.0,
  3: 7.0,
  4: 4.0,
  5: 3.0,
  6: 10.0,
  7: np.nan,
  8: np.nan},
 'level_3__category': {0: np.nan,
  1: 'a',
  2: 'c',
  3: 'a',
  4: np.nan,
  5: np.nan,
  6: np.nan,
  7: np.nan,
  8: np.nan},
 'level_3__value': {0: np.nan,
  1: 5.0,
  2: 6.0,
  3: 2.0,
  4: np.nan,
  5: np.nan,
  6: np.nan,
  7: np.nan,
  8: np.nan}})
df
```

### edit

- [Select different columns for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310268/select-different-columns-for-each-row) might be somewhat related

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but what specifically is your expected output? One dataframe? Multiple datrames? Just printing the different subsets in a loop? Can you kindly include your expected output as well?

Comment: I want to get one dataframe where all the columns with complete null values are droppend and only values of category a are present for each level.

Comment: I.e. after graph traversal of an edge list the graph is in this columnar format and I want to deletecertain nodes types from it

Comment: In your example that would return index 3 correct? That is the only row where `a` is present for all levels.

Comment: No no, I always want to return all the columns (and it is fine to return all the rows dimensions) but I want to null out (= delete all nodes which are not of category a. In the case of index 3 all categories for all levels are a - so nothing should be changed / deleted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically loop through the columns with `df.columns` and using `str.contains('level_\d+__category')` where you want to change values and then use `.where()`:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('level_\d+__category')]]
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].where(df[col] == 'a', np.nan)
df
Out[1]: 
   id level_1__category  level_1__value level_2__category  level_2__value  \
0   1                 a               1               NaN             2.0   
1   2               NaN               2               NaN             3.0   
2   3                 a               3               NaN             5.0   
3   4                 a               4                 a             7.0   
4   5                 a               5                 a             4.0   
5   6               NaN               6               NaN             3.0   
6   7                 a               7               NaN            10.0   
7   8               NaN              10               NaN             NaN   
8   9                 a              34               NaN             NaN   

  level_3__category  level_3__value  
0               NaN             NaN  
1                 a             5.0  
2               NaN             6.0  
3                 a             2.0  
4               NaN             NaN  
5               NaN             NaN  
6               NaN             NaN  
7               NaN             NaN  
8               NaN             NaN
```

Comment: Really cool! I am amazed how concise the solution is with pandas.where!

Comment: @GeorgHeiler That's why I love pandas! Please kindly accept as solution if this is what you are looking for. Thank you!